# querying user supplied URL, what are some best practices?

Tags: http, proxy

I have a web application that imports data from third-party websites by accepting a URL from a user, querying that URL, and then parsing it for data.  I'm somewhat concerned about the tool being abused so I'm wondering what best practices I should implement to mitigate abuse.  Currently the tool is only available to people who have created an account so any abuse should be traceable to a particular account.

Specifically, I was wondering if the request I send to the third-party website should include any headers such as including an IP address of the original requester (similar to a proxy request).

Comment: This is quite broad. Is there any specific kind of abuse you are concerned about?

Comment: @Anders - no, nothing specific...  I was hoping someone with more experience with this type of thing could point out some best practices to avoid some typical pitfalls.

Comment: Are you trying to protect the services you access, or are you trying to protect yourself?

Comment: @Anders - yes, both. I'm trying to avoid a possible pitfall I'm not aware of (hence the general question instead of something specific).  An example would be a user trying to do a sql injection attack via this tool (so, both protect the target and myself)

Answer (score 2):

Things that immediately come to mind for protecting other sites -

- Verify users - at a minimum by email verification.
- Per Domain Rate limiting. Both per user and global limits.
- Per user usage limits. You can also spin this into a monetiser - heavier usage for a fee
- Check Robots.txt on the remote domain and if it asks you not to run that particular request either don't do it or ask the user to confirm they have permission from the domain owner.
- Make it clear in your ToS you will pass on user details to sites where abuse has occurred and withdraw services to the user.
- Maybe offer an opt out for domain owners so that their site can't be scanned. If you do this make sure to verify they do own the domain first.

You also need to protect yourself. Remember all content pulled in from a URL could be user supplied (they may own the domain) and as such could be an attempt to exploit your own application.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things that come to my mind here.

**Limit the sites that can be accessed**
In the best case you can create a whitelist of approved sites from where data may be imported. You can then check the inputted URL against your list and assume that it likely valid.
If that is not possible certain addresses should be blacklisted (think localhost, 0.0.0.0, ..). Especially local addresses (IPv4 and IPv6) could be used to port-scan the server itself to access services that are only available from the local machine.
Maybe there is an admin panel accessible from the localhost. Or a database system running locally on a certain port that could be accessed.

**Limit the URL scheme**
Make sure that only 'http://' and 'https://' can be used in the provided URLs. Another scheme that could be used by an attacker is e.g. 'file://' to load a local file from your server. Other schemes like e.g. 'data' or 'ftp' can also be used to initiate unwanted behaviour.

**Rate-limit outgoing requests**
To prevent large numbers of outgoing requests to other sites a strict rate-limit should be applied. For a user a ten second cool-off should not be a problem. If someone wanted to use your service to hide his identity while DoSing another service a ten second delay will render this ineffective.

**Include an abuse-contact header**
You can include a header with information about how administrators can reach you if they feel abused by the requests sent by your service. That makes it reasonably easy to stop any misguided behaviour by contacting you.

**Don't execute Scripts**
I would recommend against interpreting any scripts like JavaScript code on the site you are requesting.

**Escape the URL**
Depending on the tool (if any) you use to query the content of the site, make sure to properly escape the URL to prevent any types of content or command injection attacks on your server.

Comment: The local addresses is a good point, but it's a full URL and I'm limiting it to `http` and `https` so the best they could do is access a web server that wasn't intended to be externally accessible.

Comment: While this is true for many cases, please keep in mind that there are other protocols that will respond to http requests with information even though they are not http-services. You can look up "SSRF" or "Server Side Request Forgery" for examples of this problem.

Comment: Yes, I forgot they could add a port to the URL to access other ports.

Comment: @TimTisdall research SSRF attack writeups against the language you're using. Many network libraries have weird bugs / "features" where they interpret the protocol incorrectly. You may honestly want to just setup a server on a VPS provider and just use that so they simply cannot hit your local network.

Comment: @TimTisdall - Even with HTTP/S that could include any dev servers (git/jira etc.), internal wikis etc. All you need is someone to post a password on an internal page and "the best they could do is access a web server" becomes a serious event.

Answer (score -1):

I would use a some certificate that can be issued by you to the user similar to a pki if you don't wish to use a real pki. 
Like that any user that connects needs to have the certificate.

Comment: this does not address any part of the question

Comment: Man I was thinking in using certificates as a second factor making the user Verification more efficient... (accountability) as it seems the main concern.  for the second concern perhaps a white list of the sites the users are allowed to query data might be the safest option... anything else it is not much different from a proxy in debug mode so we can parse whatever data is required...

Comment: user verification is not the main concern - in fact, the OP states that verification is already taken care of - the OP also *specifically states* that the main concern is *abuse*

Comment: My view is that if you can make a user accountable behind any reasonable doubt, abuse will cease to exist as if it happens the user will be accountable by is actions. If you have something that is public where it is hard to make someone accountable then extra abuse options should exist. It is easy and cheaper to implement accountability and monitoring than anti abuse logic.